# Shortcut to Uppercase Selected Text in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to highlight some text in a SQL Developer worksheet and convert it to uppercase with some keyboard shortcut.

Is there any such shortcut in Oracle SQL Developer?

I am using version 4.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! You can select text in your worksheet, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> to switch between cases (in version 4.1.2).

It will cycle between the following cases:

**Upper Case:**

```
SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.EXAMPLE;
```

**Lower Case:**

```
select * from myschema.example;
```

**Upper Keywords:**

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.example;
```

**Lower Keywords, Upper Identifiers:**

```
select * from MYSCHEMA.EXAMPLE;
```

**Upper Keywords, Lower Identifiers:**

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.example;
```

**Initial Cap:**

```
Select * From Myschema.Example;
```

---

As mentioned by [@PiotrSiekierski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35017613/2561365), you can change the keyboard shortcuts in `Tools -> Preferences -> Shortcut Keys`. In version 4.1.2, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> shortcut is mapped to 'Navigate Down' by default.

---

As mentioned by [@Sentinel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35018445/2561365), if you are not interested in cycling through the different case options, you can assign a shortcut to 'Convert Selection to Uppercase' or 'Convert Selection to Lowercase' by going to `Tools -> Preferences -> Shorcut Keys` and searching for the desired functionality. You can then assign a shortcut to those commands, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. In version 4.1.2, the 'Convert Selection to Uppercase' and 'Convert Selection to Lowercase' commands have no shortcut mapping by default.

Answer (score 28):

Under `Tools->Preferences->Shortcut Keys` you can find and/or define the shortcut key combination for the `Convert Selection to Uppercase` and `Convert Selection to Lowercase` commands.  I have mine mapped to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> respectively.  There unfortunately does not appear to be a specific command for converting text to Initcap, so the `To Upper/Lower/Initcap` command is the way to go for that.  However, be aware that the `To Upper/Lower/Initcap` command actually cycles between five format modes:

- UPPERCASE
- lowercase
- Initcap
- Lower Keywords, Upper Identifiers
- Upper Keywords, Lower Identifiers

Some of these modes will change the behavior of the code formatter (default key sequence <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>), and the `Tools->Preferences->Code Editor->Completion Insight->Change case as you type` setting if you have it enabled.

Comment: Great question & answer... although I would avoid to set Change case as you type. A few times I was doing very bad mistakes as it change cases as well of your text before that you put into quotes and it might hurt if you don't see the automatic change.

Comment: Nice answer! I opted for `SHIFT+CTRL+U` for upper case and `CTRL+U` for lower case as these are the default shortcuts for Notepad++, which I also use regularly. Personal preference of course!

Comment: Great, but I found only To Upper/Lower/Initcap
Convert Selection to Uppercase/Lowercase not exists ....

Comment: Just re-verified, they are still there (as of SQL Dev18.2).  In the search box above the list of shortcut keys, search for "Convert" and you'll see an abbreviated list of commands including the convert to upper and convert to lower commands.

Comment: Mine was defaulted to `ALT+'`.  I was able to discover that because of your answer.. thanks!

Answer (score 17):

in 4.2.0.17 highlight the word(s) then `Alt + '`

Answer (score 6):

This cycles through Upper/Lower/Initcap in my SQL Developer version 18.2.0.183 Build 183.1748.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps and old question, but I noticed that while on Mac, the keyboard shortcut for cycle is unbound.

I followed the above suggestions in

```
tools->preferences->shortcuts
```

and bound it myself to  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>'</kbd>  but note that in 4.2 on Mac by default this is unbound.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + ' changes case by default. You can find all shortcuts in:

```
tools->preferences->shortcuts
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have to use Ctrl + Shift + ".

Comment: Neither `Ctrl + '` nor `Ctrl + Shift + "` work for me, remapping as per the selected answer did.

Answer (score 1):

This cycles through Upper/Lower/Initcap.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have to use Ctrl + Shift + ".

Comment: @AndrewMairose depends on your keyboard language settings I would presume.

Comment: Useful to make typed text/sql code upper or lower as and when required :).

Answer (score 1):

In sql server selected text Convert in to upper case and lower case use this shortcut key

1. Upper Case : ctr + shift + U
2. Lower Case : ctr + shift + L

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Control + '
```

Everytime you press it, it toggles between camel case, lower case, and upper case. I hope this helped you.

My SQL dev is 18.4. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In newest versions you can highlight the text and then go to: Tools >> PL/SQL Beautifier and this will format your query and uppercase the text!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find the shortcut to 'Convert Selection to Uppercase' or 'Convert Selection to Lowercase' by going to Tools -> Preferences -> Shortcut Keys and searching for these, it is because you need to uncheck the "Hide Unmapped Commands" checkbox, located on the right of the search's input control.